# UIScrollView not redrawing in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I just realised that part of my App is broken on iOS 11.

I have an UIScrollView which contains multiple UIViews of which the size is only known after populating with the content. I used to set the contentSize of the scroll view once all the constrains and contents was updated, and it worked and works fine on iOS 10.

However, on iOS 11 the scroll bar on the right does show that there is movement (and so indicates '_scrollView.contentOffset.y' when I log it by monitoring 'viewDidLayoutSubviews', see below) but the visual on the screen doesn't move.

Do I need to force a redraw of the screen? What can be the cause of this.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     NSLog(@"Test, content size %f, bounds %f", _scrollView.contentSize.height, _scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

The log when scrolling:

```
2017-11-02 12:02:11.831563+0000 iDomsPortal[49338:3761141] Test, content size 1491.000000, bounds 175.666667
2017-11-02 12:02:11.839238+0000 iDomsPortal[49338:3761141] Test, content size 1491.000000, bounds 175.333333
2017-11-02 12:02:11.847142+0000 iDomsPortal[49338:3761141] Test, content size 1491.000000, bounds 175.000000
2017-11-02 12:02:12.942449+0000 iDomsPortal[49338:3761141] Test, content size 1491.000000, bounds 176.000000
2017-11-02 12:02:12.952917+0000 iDomsPortal[49338:3761141] Test, content size 1491.000000, bounds 180.333333
```

As suggested I tried:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    _scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

[EDIT:]
Food the problem. One item was referencing the top layout guide, and not the parent view. In IOS 11 the behaviour must be different and the layout guide stays static and does not move with scrolling.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

[image: Example on iPhone X simulator]

Comment: Without code its hard to says where is actual problem but try to add timer or delay method when going to add new content on new UIView

Comment: The content size, as shown in the log is right (1491) and the contentOffset correlates with the scroll bar on the side. The views within the scrollView however do not move for some reason.

Comment: Ok then try with to add scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never to your code'

Comment: I tried that but it makes no difference. I wonder if it is possible that the subviews in some way are not referenced to the scroll view view which moves but to the parent view out so. I will add a screenshot of Interface Builder and of the simulator.

Comment: Why do you have so many layout events? Do you send layoutIfNeeded somewhere?

Comment: For debugging I added a log event on '- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews', which is triggered all the time when scrolling (showing it does scroll). I found it, the top view was referenced to the Top Layout Guide, not to the superview. Changing that solved the problem it seems I guess. It makes sense, but it wasn't an issue in iOS 10.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it always helps to exchange ideas!

Comment: Ok then update your question as answer so another developer will get an ideas for that and not an issue of iOS 11. :) cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One item was referencing the top layout guide, and not the parent view. In IOS 11 the behaviour must be different and the layout guide stays static and does not move with scrolling.

Comment: I changed my constraint from Top layout guide to Superview and it works well now! Thanks